# Problema con encoding usando websphere

Tags: java, html, jsp

Bueno, el caso es que en mi cabecera html tengo las etiquetas:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

todo funciona correctamente excepto un buscador, que al buscar por la ñ no encuentra nada, para solucionarlo en mi servidor websphere añadí como argumento de JVM genérico lo siguiente: -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 y esto empezó a funcionar correctamente pero sin embargo al seleccionar datos con tildes e intentar pulsar algún botón de actualización o consulta en relación a ese dato me lleva a la ventana de error genérica ya que los datos con la tilde los recoge como irreconocibles (tan solo esa o esas letras que tienen el acento).

Answer (score 3):

> … todo funciona correctamente excepto un buscador …

Si agregas la propiedad **`-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8`**, le estás indicando a WebSphere cuál es la codificación que debe usar (sólo cuando ésta **no** es especificada, p.ej.: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) para leer los parámetros del contenido de una petición `POST` o los parámetros en un *query string*. Diferente a **`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`**, el cual cambiará la codificación por defecto utilizada al leer o escribir archivos, etc.

Si antes de especificar esta propiedad, el buscador no funcionada correctamente, eso podría significar que el buscador enviaba los datos codificados en UTF-8, pero WebSphere los decodificaba usando ISO-8859-1.

Por ejemplo, la palabra `IBAÑEZ` puede enviarse como `IBA%C3%91EZ` (UTF-8) o `IBA%D1EZ` (ISO-8859-1). Si el servidor recibe `IBA%C3%91EZ` (UTF-8), entonces WebSphere lo podría decodificar en UTF-8 como `IBAÑEZ` (`IBA\u00D1EZ`) ✔ o en ISO-8859-1 como `IBAÃEZ` (`IBA\u00C3\u0091EZ`) ✘.

> … sin embargo al seleccionar datos con tildes e intentar pulsar algún botón de actualización o consulta en relación a ese dato me lleva a la ventana de error genérica ya que los datos con la tilde los recoge como irreconocibles …

Asumiendo que *todo* funcionaba correctamente antes de agregar  la propiedad **`-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8`**, entonces eso significa que está decodificando con UTF-8 los datos recibidos como ISO-8859-1. Es decir, si WebSphere recibe `IBA%D1EZ` (ISO-8859-1), ahora lo decodifica en UTF-8 como `IBA�EZ` (`IBA\uFFFDEZ`) ✘.

---

Debes asegurarte que los datos se **envían** como UTF-8. Si tienes formularios que se envían sin AJAX, entonces agrega el atributo `accept-charset`. Es es:

```
<form … accept-charset="UTF-8" … >
```

Con JavaScript, utiliza la función [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) o [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (según sea el caso) para codificar los datos a enviar en UTF-8 con AJAX. jQuery utiliza UTF-8 para codificar objetos (p.ej.: `{ nombre: var2 }`) en `data`.

En caso de que cambies la cabecera de los JSPs a `UTF-8` (cambiando también la codificación del archivo mismo), lo anterior puede ser opcional en la mayoría de los navegadores, excepto posiblemente en [Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153527).

Comment: me sucede exactamente lo segundo que has mencionado, es decir, que decodifica con UTF-8 los datos recibidos como ISO-8859-1, creo que me has dado buenas soluciones, pero no las entiendo muy bien por mi falta de experiencia para plasmarlas sobre la aplicación. ¿Crees que puedes darme algún tipo de orientación algo más fácil?

Comment: Si lo único que no funcionaba antes era el buscador, entonces hay que modificar la forma en cómo envía los datos. ¿Cómo estás enviando los datos? ¿Con JavaScript, jQuery, o es un `submit`, etc?

Comment: Buenas @PaulVargas, envía los datos a través de formulario por action y creo que el fallo se debe a que por defecto struts tiene un enctype raro. Se lo estoy intentando cambiar y buscando el que coja las ñ pero no doy con él. Voy bien encaminado?

Comment: Supongo que estás usando html:form. Puedes cambiar esos tags por HTML ordinario. Depende la complejidad. [Aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20226627/870248) hay un ejemplo.

Comment: Efectivamente, si bueno tendría que tocar todos los formularios, encontré la siguiente solución, es también un poco coñazo y preferiría algo más global y generalizado pero bueno, esto está bien:
currentForm.setVB(AU.searchTableJQuery(new String(request.getParameter("variable").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8")));

Comment: ¡Ah! Excelente. ¿Quitaste el argumento de la JVM? — Sí, esa puede ser una solución *por lo mientras*. Las otras soluciones implican hacer muchos cambios en muchas partes... y a veces no se tiene el tiempo disponible. ;)

Comment: Si @PaulVargas lo quité, es decir lo deje todo como estaba exceptuando añadir en código lo comentado en el anterior comentario. Muchas gracias espero que alguien pueda llegar a los comentarios para dar con la solución si tuviesen el mismo problema. Gracias amigo.

Answer (score 2):

El encoding ahora de la JVM está en UTF-8, y lo que le mandas desde el JSP es  charset=ISO-8859-1 , posiblemente genera caracteres que no reconoce como los que llevan tilde:
**éxito
Ã©xito**
Intenta dejando el mismo encoding a tu vista JSP:

Se recomienda usar el mismo encoding que tienes en el Meta, UTF-8 es más amplio que Latin 1 (otro nombre de iso-8859-1), tiene más caracteres y por lo tanto se puede usar para muchos más idiomas sin problemas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: Adicional a ello, hay que asegurarse de que los archivos se guarden en formato UTF-8.

Comment: @Ventura ya probé eso y no me funcionó, lo leí por internet y quise asegurarme antes de formular la pregunta, es lo que me resulta extraño... Alguna solución diferente? Perdón por no haber añadido en mi pregunta que ya probé esa solución...